# Create sysfs entry from kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

I want to pass a string > 1024 chars to my module (filesystem).
As kernel parameters are limited to 1024 chars, [someone recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658368/string-length-limit-for-a-kernel-module-parameter) to use sysfs instead.

I tried to include [this example](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/code/sysfs_ex.c) in my super.c class to create a string 'filename' & string 'code' entry in sysfs for my module.

```
static decl_subsys(myfs, NULL, NULL);

struct myfs_attr {
    struct attribute attr;
    char *value;
};

static struct myfs_attr fname = {
    .attr.name="filename",
    .attr.owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .attr.mode = 0644,
    .value = "/my/test/path",
};

static struct myfs_attr code = {
    .attr.name="code",
    .attr.owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .attr.mode = 0644,
    .value = "0101",
};
```

When compiling my module I get a lot of errors (line 41 is decl_subsys):

```
fs/myfs/super.c:41:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘(’ token
fs/myfs/super.c:50:2: error: unknown field ‘owner’ specified in initializer
fs/myfs/super.c:50:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:50:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘fname.attr.name’) [enabled by default]
...
fs/myfs/super.c: At top level:
fs/myfs/super.c:83:15: error: variable ‘myfsops’ has initializer but incomplete type
fs/myfs/super.c:84:2: error: unknown field ‘show’ specified in initializer
fs/myfs/super.c:84:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:84:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘myfsops’) [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:85:2: error: unknown field ‘store’ specified in initializer
fs/myfs/super.c:85:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:85:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘myfsops’) [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:89:2: error: unknown field ‘myfs_ops’ specified in initializer
fs/myfs/super.c:89:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c:89:2: warning: (near initialization for ‘myfstype.release’) [enabled by default]
fs/myfs/super.c: In function ‘init_myfs_fs’:
fs/myfs/super.c:1554:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘kobj_set_kset_s’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
fs/myfs/super.c:1554:19: error: ‘myfs_subsys’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fs/myfs/super.c:1554:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
fs/myfs/super.c:1554:32: error: ‘fs_subsys’ undeclared (first use in this function)
fs/myfs/super.c:1557:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘subsystem_register’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
fs/myfs/super.c: In function ‘exit_myfs_fs’:
fs/myfs/super.c:1579:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘subsystem_unregister’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
fs/myfs/super.c:1579:24: error: ‘myfs_subsys’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

1. Is this tutorial just outdated for my 3.5 kernel or am I missing something else?
2. How could I create 2 char string entries for my module in sysfs?

Comment: The documentation you're looking at is indeed rather outdated — it's from July 2008, and was written for the 2.6.23 kernel.

Comment: This looks very complicated. What about providing your parameter to a char device by implementing the `read` function instead?

Comment: Most articles about kernel programming say that you shouldn't use `read` in kernel modules, therefore I wanted to avoid using it.

Comment: Can you paste your full code or provide link to code, so that we can debug? Also, please provide details about OS and Kernel Version

Answer (score 8):

Here is the source code for transmitting data to a "param_buf" string. As requested, without read method. Only store.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/string.h>

static struct kobject *register_kobj;
static char *param_buf;

// function for many symbol data enter
static ssize_t __used store_value(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count){ 
    printk(KERN_ALERT "you entered %s\n", buf);
    strncpy(param_buf, buf, PAGE_SIZE - 1);
    return count;
}

// register function to attribute
static struct kobj_attribute store_val_attribute = __ATTR( put_parameters, 0220, NULL, store_value);

// put attribute to attribute group
static struct attribute *register_attrs[] = {
    &store_val_attribute.attr,
    NULL,   /* NULL terminate the list*/
};
static struct attribute_group  reg_attr_group = {
    .attrs = register_attrs
};

static int hello_init(void){
    param_buf = kzalloc(PAGE_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
    // create sysfs object ( /sys/kernel/test_1025_sym directory )
    register_kobj = kobject_create_and_add("test_1025_sym", kernel_kobj);
    if (!register_kobj)
    return -ENOMEM;

    //create attributes (files)
    if(sysfs_create_group(register_kobj, &reg_attr_group)){
        kobject_put(register_kobj);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "last value was %s\n", param_buf);
    kfree(param_buf);
    kobject_put(register_kobj);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

You can test it in such a way:

```
cat /etc/fstab > /sys/kernel/test_1025_sym/put_parameters
```

For two string entries: copy a store_value function, register one more store_val_attribute and put it to attributes list.

Comment: I get this : [10408.532457] you entered # UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
               /dev/mmcblk0p1  /  auto  errors=remount-ro  0  1
Is it expected.?

Comment: I think this should be accepted as the correct answer.Except that the permission to be changed to 0660 from 0222 otherwise it will give build error  : nclude/linux/bug.h:33:45: error: negative width in bit-field ‘<anonymous>’
 #define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
                                             ^

Comment: With a small correction.
In this question have an item about write only mode
So I change the permissions to 0220

Comment: JFYI: `param_buf` leak?